# GET x-Auth-Token via JavaScript/Angular/Ionic Promise

Tags: javascript, angularjs, authentication, ionic-framework

I have a problem and don´t know how to solve it...
I have to authenticate a user in my IonicApp through a token based authentication. So i have to store the token inside the app, which shouldn´t be a problem...
The Problem is: How can i get the token?
Here´s my code:

```
    // Alle Aufrufe an die REST-Api werden hier durchgeführt
    var httpCall = {
        async : function(method, url, header, params, data) {
//          if (url != 'login') {
//              header['X-Auth-Token'] = userTokenFactory.getUserToken();
//          }
            //console.log(header['X-Auth-Token']);
            var ipurl = "IPURL";
            // $http returns a promise, which has a then function, which also returns a promise
            var promise = $http({
                method : method,
                url : ipurl + url,
                //headers : header,
                params : params,
                data : data,
                config : {
                    timeout : 5000
                }
            }).then(function successCallback(response) {
                //console.log("data:" + response.data);
                //console.log("header:" + response.headers);
                console.log("token:" + response.headers['X-AUTH-TOKEN']);
                //console.log(response.data.token);
                console.log("token" + repsonse.token);
                // TRY TO READ THE X_AUTH_TOKEN HERE !!!!!!!!!!!!
                return response;
            }, function errorCallback(response) {
                return response;
            });
            // Return the promise to the controller
            return promise;
        }
    };
    return httpCall;
});
```

And here´s a picture of the Response from the Server (from Firefox). As you can see, the X-Auth-Token is there...
[here´s the x-auth-token](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3za17.jpg)

Thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 0):

There are lot of articles are available over handling authentication in AngularJS. [This article](https://auth0.com/blog/2014/01/07/angularjs-authentication-with-cookies-vs-token/) is the one perfect suitable in your case.

So you can get token from your request as,

```
}).then(function successCallback(response) {
    console.log("data:" + response.data);
    $window.sessionStorage.token = response.data.token;
    return response;
}, function errorCallback(response) {
    return response;
});
```

Now we have the token saved in sessionStorage. This token can be sent back with each request by at least three ways

### 1. Set header in each request:

```
`$http({method: 'GET', url: url, headers: {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + $window.sessionStorage.token}
});`
```

### 2. Setting defaults headers

```
`$http.defaults.headers.common['X-Auth-Token'] = 'Bearer ' + $window.sessionStorage.token;`
```

### 3. Write `Interceptor`:

> Interceptors give ability to intercept requests before they are
>   handed to the server and responses before they are handed over to the
>   application code that initiated these requests

```
myApp.factory('authInterceptor', function ($rootScope, $q, $window) {
  return {
    request: function (config) {
      config.headers = config.headers || {};
      if ($window.sessionStorage.token) {
        config.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + $window.sessionStorage.token;
      }
      return config;
    },
    response: function (response) {
      if (response.status === 401) {
        // handle the case where the user is not authenticated
      }
      return response || $q.when(response);
    }
  };
});

myApp.config(function ($httpProvider) {
  $httpProvider.interceptors.push('authInterceptor');
});
```

Refer AngularJS [$http guide](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#post) for detailed explanation.

As you are getting response.data null and image demonstrates that headers are being returned, I would suggest you to check if you are getting data with

`response.headers()`,

if then try with `response.headers()["X_AUTH_TOKEN"]`.

Comment: yes, i read this article...
But, however, this article gets the token by "response.data.token", but in my case the response.data is empty, and the x-auth-token is send in the header, as you can see in my picture... so this isn´t helpful :/