# JWT Token is not setting on Headers in $resource

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, jwt

I am using JWT for User Authorization. I am inserting data in mongodb with Node API. Now I want to insert loggedin User's id in to mongodb along with data.

**Angular**

```
//factory for blog insert
app.factory('blogFactory', function($resource, $rootScope){
  return $resource('/api/addblog/:id', {id:'@_id'},{get:{headers:{'authorization':$rootScope.token}}});
});

//controller for add blog

    app.controller('blogpostCtrl', function($rootScope, $scope, blogFactory, $location){

      $scope.addBlog=function(){
          $scope.blogg=new blogFactory($scope.blog); 
          $scope.blogg.$save(function(){ 
            $scope.blog=" ";
              $scope.alert="Blog Successfully Inserted..!!!";
                });
      };
    });
```

**Node api**

```
apiRoutes.post('/addblog', function(req, res){ 
  var tokenx=req.headers.authorization;
  console.log(tokenx);
  var loggedinUser= jwt.decode(tokenx, config.secret);

  var CurrentDate=Date.now(); 
  var newBlog=new blogModel({
    title:req.body.title, 
    description:req.body.description, 
    category:req.body.category,  
    date:CurrentDate,
    by:loggedinUser._id
  });
  newBlog.save(function(err, data){
    if(err){return res.json({success:false, msg:'Blog Not Posted'})}
      else{
        res.json({success:true, msg:'Successfully Posted'});
      }
  });

});
```

So, I want to know that, Is it the right way to write `headers` in `$resource` with angular js. 
When I execute this code its showing an error `Error: No Token Supplied`. and in `console.log` an error is also showing `POST http://localhost:3000/api/addblog 500 (Internal Server Error)`.

Please help.

Comment: are you getting value in `req.headers.authorization`?

Comment: no.. Its `undefined`

Comment: In angular side you get `$rootScope.token` this value during sending?

Comment: Can you show your main server file?

Comment: Yes `$rootScope.token` having token

Comment: Can you show your app.js file?

Comment: How to show?.. I have to past code here?

Comment: See my updated answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Your header must be included in Access-Control-Allow-Headers header in response to the OPTIONS request.

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {

  // Website you wish to allow to connect
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');

  // Request methods you wish to allow
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');

  // Request headers you wish to allow
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type,authorization');

  // Set to true if you need the website to include cookies in the requests sent
  // to the API (e.g. in case you use sessions)
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);

  // Pass to next layer of middleware
  next();
});
```

**Edit**

You can see multiple ways to send your request with `angular.js`

[how to set custom headers with a $resource action?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18924217/how-to-set-custom-headers-with-a-resource-action)

Comment: Did you try @nitish answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18924217/how-to-set-custom-headers-with-a-resource-action

Comment: yes.... @nitish's answer is working... now `console.log(req.headers.authorization);` is printing `token`

Comment: I am adding this answer in my answer so that anyone can easily find  it

Answer (score 0):

There are may ways you can set authorization token in request, it will be based on use case.
here is the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35817196/get-x-auth-token-via-javascript-angular-ionic-promise/35827608#35827608) I wrote, may be helpful to you.